# How to execute task in multiple host according to the hostname defined in variables

Tags: ansible, jinja2

```
 content of inventory file: 

all:
  vars:
    rsyslog_server: SERVER-1,SERVER-2 # It can have one or more server 

content of my  task is:

- name: Copy server file in to /etc/rsyslog.d
  template:
    src: ../templates/server.j2
    dst: /etc/rsyslog.d/server.conf
  when: ansible_hostname == rsyslog_server
```

I want to execute the playbook task on server defined in variable. According to the condition. I have some client as well. How can I check if the hostname is either SERVER-1,SERVER-2 or any other value defined in variable  and execute the task. My client machine will be skipping the task. How can I acheive this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loof for `ansible_hostname` inside `rsyslog_server` var

```yaml
- name: Copy server file in to /etc/rsyslog.d
  template:
    src: ../templates/server.j2
    dst: /etc/rsyslog.d/server.conf
  when: rsyslog_server | search(ansible_hostname)
```

Or you can look for `ansible_hostname` inside a list from `rsyslog_server` var

```yaml
- name: Copy server file in to /etc/rsyslog.d
  template:
    src: ../templates/server.j2
    dst: /etc/rsyslog.d/server.conf
  when: ansible_hostname in rsyslog_server.split(',')
```